# Is there any other proper class beside the universal class?

Tags: set-theory

given $Set(x) \iff \exists Cls(A): x\epsilon A$

and $\neg Set(x) \iff \neg \exists Cls(A): x\epsilon A$ the definition of a proper class

and the universal class V being the class containing all sets $\forall Set(x): x\epsilon V$

is every proper class = V ? $\forall(x):\neg Set(x) \iff x=V ?$

for clarification i'm talking in the context of [NBG](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Von_Neumann%E2%80%93Bernays%E2%80%93G%C3%B6del_set_theory)

Comment: I don't know NBG, but the class of all singleton sets is definitely not $V$ and it's definitely not a set.  I would assume this class could be defined in whatever context that allows you to define $V$ itself..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The class of all ordinals is proper. Indeed, if a set, it would itself be well-ordered and ultimately an ordinal, hence element of itself — immediately contradicting said well order!

For other straightforward examples, note that the union of two sets is a set, hence for any set $A$, the class $V\setminus A$ is proper.